# Toral automorphism has positive entropy iff $\mu \left( (B+tv^-) \cap B \right) >0$ for infinitely many $t$

Tags: measure-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, entropy

Let $X = \mathbb T^2=\mathbb R^2/\mathbb Z^2$ be the torus, $\mu$ a $T$-invariant measure on $X$, $A \in M_2(\mathbb Z)$ a hyperbolic matrix, $T_A$ the associated automorphism. Let $v^-$ be an eigenvector of the smaller eigenvalue. (The contracting eigenvector.)

We want to prove:

> $h_\mu(T_a)>0$ if and only if for every $B$ with $\mu(B)>0$, there are arbitrarily large $t$ for which $\mu \left( (B+tv^-) \cap B \right) >0$.

This resembles the definitions of non-wandering set and conservative action, for $\mathbb R$-actions.

### Observations in the comments:

- The translations along $v^{-}$ may not be measure-preserving, so we cannot apply Poincaré recurrence.
- The claim is easy in case $\mu$ is the Haar measure $m_X$.

Comment: Surely you see that you need to prove that the slopes are irrational...In my opinion the other direction is the complicated one.

Comment: Let me add that the sentence "This is the continuous analog of being a conservative $\mathbb Z$-action." makes no sense. In this setting (let aside infinite ergodic theory) "conservative" is just being "Haar".

Comment: The question is strange. The condition $\mu((B+tv^-)\cap B)>0$ for arbitrary large $t$ is always satisfied. Indeed, the flow of translation by $v^-$ is measure-preserving, so this is only Poincaré recurrence (even if $v^-$ has rational slope).

Comment: @user120527 Is there a version of Poincaré recurrence that gives every $B$ with $\mu(B)>0$ a time where a positive measure of it returns? The version I know just says that almost every point, separately, returns infinitely many times. In any way, when the slopes are irrational, this is an ergodic transformation so every two sets of positive measure $\mu(A)\mu(B)>0$ have a time where they intersect in positive measure:  $\mu(T^{-n}(A)\cap B)>0$ as needed here.

Comment: Yes. For almost every $x\in B$, the (integer) return time $\tau_B(x)=\inf\{k\geq1: x+kv^-\in B\}$ is finite. So, up to a measure zero set , $B=\cup_{k\geq 1} \tau_B^{-1}(k)$. So for at least one $k\geq 1$, $\tau_B^{-1}(k)\subset B\cap (B-kv^-)$ has positive measure.

Comment: I don't quite understand why you are trying to prove the stated result. The entropy of any hyperbolic toral automorphism with respect to Haar measure is $\log \lambda$, where $\lambda>1$ is the largest (Perron-Frobenius) eigenvalue, so it is always positive. (Incidentally, this is also the topological entropy, so Haar measure is a measure of maximal entropy.)

Comment: @LukasGeyer Thank you, I added "Haar" in the formulation absent-mindedly. The claim is about a general measure.

Comment: @Pachirisu: Oh, I see, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: And by the way, there is no reason that the flow along the $v^-$ direction is measure-preserving, so Poincare recurrence simply does not apply here. (As a simple example, the point measure at $0$ is $T$-invariant, but certainly not invariant under this flow.)

Comment: Now that the invariant measure is not Haar anymore, one should probably add ergodicity to the hypotheses, otherwise the statement is false.

Comment: You changed the measure, but really nothing changes: again you need to show that the slopes are irrational. Unrelated to Poincaré recurrence by the way. You certainly have many **nonatomic** measures that are not Haar, but the argument is again the same. You should look for nonzero Lyapunov exponents and this is related to the existence of irrational slopes. In this "more difficult direction", an easy escape is to note that topological entropy is positive (variational principle) so nothing changes if Haar is replaced by any measure of positive entropy.

Comment: To elaborate on @user120527 comment, the "only if" direction fails for non-ergodic measures. If $\mu = \frac12(\mu_0 + \delta_0)$ where $\mu_0$ is Haar measure and $\delta_0$ is the point measure at $0$, then $\mu$ is $T$-invariant with positive entropy, but the statement fails for $B = \{ 0 \}$.